# Failed to send index value to an entity in Hibernate?

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate

Good afternoon, I'm developing with Hibernate using SQL-QUERY, I've been able to capture the data from the list, and setting it to the attributes of the entity, I only need one, is as follows:

```
Query query = sessionFactory.openSession().getNamedQuery("getListCustomers");
        query.setResultTransformer(new ResultTransformer() { 
            public Object transformTuple(Object[] aux, String[] aliases) { 
                Customer item = new Customer(); 
                item.setCustomerId(((BigDecimal) aux[0]).longValue());
                item.getCompany().setCompanyId(((BigDecimal) (aux[1]!=null?aux[1]:0)).longValue()); // Failed
                item.setCode(aux[2]!=null?aux[2].toString():"");
                item.setName(aux[3]!=null?aux[3].toString():"");                
                return item; 
            }
            public List transformList(List collection) { 
                return collection; 
            }
        });
```

The problem is that the attribute company has relationship another entity, according to the mapping relates to the other entity CompanyId

```
public class Customer {
    private Long customerId;
    private Company company;
}
```

I get the following error message in console:

```
[Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException]
```

Comment: where did you get the NPE?

Comment: My crystal ball tells me `item.getCompany()` is null, you should lookup the company (from db) and use `setCompany()` if existing or create a new one.